# `Descope` error - ReferenceError: document is not defined. How to resolve?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm a newbie to Descope. So, I created an account, installed the react sdk, and set it up in my NextJs app. However, running the app I got this error:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at /path-to-my-project/frontend/node_modules/@descope/web-component/dist/index.js:2:10430
    at Object.<anonymous> (path-to-my-project/frontend/node_modules/@descope/web-component/dist/index.js:2:42047)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1257:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:962:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:165:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:192:25)
    at async DefaultModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:246:24)
    at async file:path-to-my-project/frontend/node_modules/@descope/react-sdk/dist/index.esm.js:1:1840
```

Even more details from the `Network` tab this was logged in the response:

```
{
    "errorCode": "E011002",
    "errorDescription": "Request is missing required arguments",
    "errorMessage": "Missing JWT for refresh session",
    "message": "Missing JWT for refresh session"
}
```

How do I resolve this?